# Persist to google assistant data to a Database ( The data fetched from google assistant dialog )?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am able to get data using google actions but need your help in store this data into the database so that the user does not have to provide information every time he interacts with my action . Any help on this please

I am developing a stock app , collects names and quantity of various company names  the user has invested in. , post that user should be able to ask various questions about his portfolio on a day to day basis ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is a preliminary stage : As of now i am able to store stock names with respective quantities and repeat it back to user                                             Once i learn how to store into the database will provide a CRUD and then design the intents :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to persist user data is to use the built-in [user storage feature](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data). This will allow you to save data for a user across conversations.

Here's an example of how it works:

```
function simpleResponse(conv) {
  conv.user.storage.count = 1;
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
  speech: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about ' +
      'almost any number, like 42. What do you have in mind?',
  text: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any ' +
      'number. What do you have in mind?',
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton will try it